# Why can't selenium webdriver see the elements on the webpage? (NoSuchElementException)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have my selenium code here

```
        System.out.println("Selects selected");

        Methods methods = new Methods();

        /**
            there's some code here, but it's just a lot of driver().findElement() and updating values in fields. It works OK
        **/

        driver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"updateclient\"]")).click();

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        driver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"quoteclient\"]")).click();

        Thread.sleep(15000);

        /* Selects the Zurich Quote (Only one currently working) */
        driver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'quote-0')]//*[contains(@alt, 'Zurich')]")).click();

        /* Select the Apply for Big 3 CIC button */
        driver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"apply_for_big3\"]")).click();

        //Just wait for the page to load properly
        Thread.sleep(2500);

        /**
         * Now we are at the big3 eligibility page. We will need to enter the client details.
         * Because we want to check all the outcomes that iptiQ have given us, we're going to do
         * this in a loop.
         *
         * This loop will set the client details, answer the questions, and then go through to the
         * quoting page.
         *
         * When the client has been quoted for the values set, we will check that the premium matches
         * the expected value.
         *
         * At the end of each iteration, the user will be returned to the Big3 eligibility screen so that
         * the next set of values can be set.
         */

        //Get the fields. -------
        //This is the bit that keeps failing and it should not be failing
        // because the elements are all present on the page
        WebElement EligibilityTitleOne = driver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"title_1\"]"));
        WebElement EligibilityForenameOne = driver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"forename_1\"]"));
        WebElement EligibilitySurnameOne = driver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"surname_1\"]"));

        String[][] SumAssuredCases = QuoteGraph.SingleLifeSumAssured;

        for(int i=0; i<SumAssuredCases.length; i++){

/**
            //Extract all the required values from the array
            int AgeNextBirthDay = Integer.parseInt(SumAssuredCases[i][1]);
            String SmokerStatus = SumAssuredCases[i][2];
            String SumAssured = SumAssuredCases[i][5].replace(",","");
            String PolicyTerm = SumAssuredCases[i][6];
            String ExpectedPremium = SumAssuredCases[i][7];
            String ExpectedCommission = SumAssuredCases[i][8];
 **/

int AgeNextBirthDay = 25;
String SmokerStatus = "NonSmoker";
String SumAssured = "10000";

            //We are going to use a pre set name, as names do not affect the premium.
            EligibilityTitleOne.clear();
            EligibilityTitleOne.sendKeys("Mr");
            System.out.println("Set customer 1 title");
            EligibilityForenameOne.clear();
            EligibilityForenameOne.sendKeys("Tester");
            System.out.println("Set customer 1 forename");
            EligibilitySurnameOne.clear();
            EligibilitySurnameOne.sendKeys("Testeez");
            System.out.println("Set customer 1 surname");

            //Now we are going to set the sex to be male. This does not affect the premium.
            Select clientOneSexSelect = new Select(driver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gender_1\"]")));
            clientOneSexSelect.selectByVisibleText("Male");
            System.out.println("Set customer 1 to male");

            //Now we need to set the smoker status from the value in the customer profile
            Select clientOneSmokerStat = new Select(driver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"smoker_1\"]")));
            if(SmokerStatus.matches("Smoker")) {
                clientOneSmokerStat.selectByVisibleText("Yes");
                System.out.println("Customer 1 is a smoker.");
            } else {
                clientOneSmokerStat.selectByVisibleText("No");
                System.out.println("Customer 1 is not a smoker.");
            }

            //Now we need to calculate the date of birth
            String customerOneDob = methods.DOBFromAge(AgeNextBirthDay);
            driver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"dob_1\"]")).sendKeys(customerOneDob);
            System.out.println("Customer 1 date of birth set to " + customerOneDob);

            //Now we need to set the sum assured value
            driver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"sum_assured\"]")).clear();
            driver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"sum_assured\"]")).sendKeys(SumAssured);
            System.out.println("Sum assured set to £" + SumAssured);

            //Select the update client details
            driver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"update_lead\"]")).click();

            //Wait for update to complete
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("The changes have been saved.");

            Thread.sleep(2500);
        }
```

and all the `driver().findElement(By.xpath())` have worked fine up until the point when I need to fill out the form repeatedly in the loop, and suddenly I start getting the `NoSuchElementException` error.

I don't understand why I am getting the error, when the webpage I am on has all the fields, I have taken the xpaths directly from `[right click]->[copy xpath]` in devtools.

The fields are definitely there and the XPATH I am using is correct, I've checked multiple times and so have my colleages, but I don't know why it gets to just before the loop and then stops working.

I've also tried `findElement(By.id())` but that still gave me the same error. Selenium is acting as though the elements don't exist, even though they do.

Comment: may be id values are dynamic like title_1, title_2, etc. you can check whether it is same for every time or not? or it may be inside frame.

Comment: @Murthi, they are the same value every time.

Comment: please check whether the elements are inside a iframe or not?

Comment: Hang on, I think i've made a noob error. The window is opening in a different tab.

Comment: @Murthi, yeah, I made a noob error. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the elements are with in IFrame then use driver.switchto.frame (frmaelocator);
2. If it's on a different tab use windowhandles